# CMake Error: The source directory "/home/pi" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: opencv, setup

Can someone please tell me what I have to? I'm trying to setup my build using CMake. My code and its' error is the following. How do I make CMakeLists?

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/build $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.4.14/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/pi" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Comment: Perhaps `cmake .` initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing this command in the wrong folder. You should create a `build` subdirectory in the folder where you cloned OpenCV and run the command from there if you use `..` as an argument to CMake.

Alternatively, replace `..` by the actual path to the OpenCV source code, this is what they recommend in the official installation instructions: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

> `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`

Are you sure you want to install it to `/usr/local`? You seem to have a Python virtual environment active, do you want to install OpenCV system-wide or only in the virtual environment? In case of the latter, you might want to use `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$VIRTUAL_ENV"`.